# Can not find deleted image

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

The function I wrote on the node JS server does not delete the image. He can't find the picture. But when you type the name of the picture, it deletes it from the folder.

I get this error:

failed to delete local image:Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'C:\Users\mary\Desktop\Node.js-UploadFiles-RestAPIs\uploads\undefined'

NodeJS : File Controller

```
const uploadFolder = __basedir + '/uploads/';
const fs = require('fs');


exports.deleteFile=(req, res)=> {

    let filename = req.params.filename;
    fs.unlink(uploadFolder + filename, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("failed to delete local image:"+err);
        } else {
            console.log('successfully deleted local image');                                
        }
});

}
```

NodeJS : File Router

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();


let fileWorker = require('../controllers/file.controller.js');

router.delete('/api/file/delete', fileWorker.deleteFile);

module.exports = router;
```

Service.ts :

```
    delete(file : File):Observable<HttpEvent<{}>>{
      // const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
      // formdata.append('file' , file);
      const req = new HttpRequest('DELETE', 'http://localhost:8000/api/file/delete',file, {
        responseType: 'text'

      });
      return this.http.request(req);
    }
```

component.ts :

```
  x:any[];

  deleteImage(y){

  // @ts-ignore
  this.x=getFile();

    this.imageServis.delete(y).subscribe(event => {

      console.log("Here");

    });
}
```

Comment: your `req.params.filename` is undefined

Comment: I know. what can ı do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the undefined in your error :

**'C:\Users\mary\Desktop\Node.js-UploadFiles-RestAPIs\uploads\undefined'**

Filename is not define in your function :

```
exports.deleteFile=(req, res)=> {

    let filename = req.params.filename;
    fs.unlink(uploadFolder + filename, (err) => {
```

You use req.params but it seems that you send the filename in the body :

```
 const req = new HttpRequest('DELETE', 'http://localhost:8000/api/file/delete',file, {
    responseType: 'text'

  });
```

If you want to use req.params do the following :

```
 const req = new HttpRequest('DELETE', 'http://localhost:8000/api/file/delete'+file,null, {
    responseType: 'text'

  });


router.delete('/api/file/delete/:filename', fileWorker.deleteFile);
```

Comment: Now I get this error:  failed to delete local image:Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'C:\Users\mary\Desktop\Node.js-UploadFiles-RestAPIs\uploads\[object File]'

Comment: Please print the content of the variable "file" in  const req = new HttpRequest('DELETE', 'http://localhost:8000/api/file/delete'+file,

Comment: sorry, this is the correct error: DELETE http://localhost:8000/api/file/delete[object%20File] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please print the content of the variable "file" in const req = new HttpRequest('DELETE', 'localhost:8000/api/file/delete'+file,

Comment: console.log(file);
const req = new HttpRequest('DELETE', 'http://localhost:8000/api/file/delete'+file,  file is currently an object, we need to know which key is containing the filename

Comment: key is containing the filename : name

Comment: solution : 'DELETE', 'http://localhost:8000/api/file/delete/'+file.name,null,                                               ı solved :) thank you